# QGIS - Matching Exported Files to Print Layout Exports

Tags: qgis, dem, qgis-export

I am exporting a u16 bit DEM of New Zealand's South Island using the save as > raw data method and specifying a lower resolution (to reduce the file size). This is after warping the data to my chosen CRS.

I want to also export other raster (sattelite raster) and shapefiles (rivers, lakes, etc) to overlay the DEM in photoshop, however I'm unsure of the best way to do this.

With the raster sattelite data, the projection of the output does not match that of the DEM, even after translating. It's worth mentioning here that I am creating a VRT to merge the sattelite files instead of the Merge tool, and assuming that this won't affect future reprojection processes.

With the Shapefiles, I am exporting these as a raster via the print layout export, and the scale does match however due to rasterization I lose the benefit of the SVG format of these files.

It would be great to know from you more experienced QGIS members how you go about exporting to avoid the issues I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

One way will be to export your `Print Layout` as `.pdf` with `Always Export as  Vectors` toggled on. If you select `Create Geospatial PDF`, then your `.pdf` file will have georeferencing information and in addition, will keep layers as in your project. Now open this pdf it in `Inkscape` or any similar vector editors.  This way your vector layers will be preserved. However, beware of any pattern symbology you have created in `QGIS` as these will overflow polygon boundaries.
If you are saving your `DEM` as `GeoTIFF` files, you can use file compression rather than reducing the resolution to restrict the file size.
If you use a common clip for all your layers, and resample all raster layers to same pixel size, you can get rid of the mismatch when opening in `Photoshop`.